# packing an incrementing counter into hex with perl

Tags: perl, hex, pack

i am trying to create a 12 byte header and i am using pack. everything was going awesome until i needed to include an incrementing value in the pack function..

EDIT:

i have an open ffmpeg pipe that i am capturing the output from. the captured data is going to be a payload that will be encrypted and appended to the end of the header. my loop is not a for loop but i thought i would make it a little easier for the readers to understand.

so let me update the question here in hopes it clears any confusion. if i need to provide any more information let me know.

```
my $m = 00;
my $n = 00;

while( <$source_audio> ) { 
    if(($n % 16) == 0){
        $m++; #this should increment when n reaches 0xff
    }
    my $header = pack( 'C C n n C*', 0x80, 0x78, $m, $n, 0x12, 0x34, 0x98, 0x76, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04 );
    print $file $header ;
    $n++;
}
```

i just need to be able to pack $m and $n so i get the expected output:

```
80 78 00 01 12 34 98 76 01 02 03 04
80 78 00 02 12 34 98 76 01 02 03 04
80 78 00 03 12 34 98 76 01 02 03 04
80 78 00 04 12 34 98 76 01 02 03 04
80 78 00 05 12 34 98 76 01 02 03 04
... iterating 0x0000 to 0xFFFF ...
80 78 FF FB 12 34 98 76 01 02 03 04
80 78 FF FC 12 34 98 76 01 02 03 04
80 78 FF FD 12 34 98 76 01 02 03 04
80 78 FF FE 12 34 98 76 01 02 03 04
80 78 FF FF 12 34 98 76 01 02 03 04
```

EDIT2:

this gives me the desired output, but i get errors with strict and warnings enabled:

```
my $m = 0x00;
my $n = 0x00;

my $message = "this";

while ( <$source_audio> ) {
    my $header = pack('C*', 0x80, 0x78, $m, $n, 0x12, 0x34, 0x98, 0x76, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04);
    
    if(($n % 0xFF) == 0 and $n != 0x00){
        $m++;
    }
    
    $n++;
print $temp $header;
}
```

```
Character in 'C' format wrapped in pack
```

Solution was exactly as ikegami pointed out:

```
pack('C C n C*', 0x80, 0x78, $n, 0x12, 0x34, 0x98, 0x76, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with `pack` or your use of it. The problem is that you are miscalculating `$m` and `$n`. The warning is the result of `$m` exceeding `0xFF`, which clearly should not happen.

The following properly calculates `$m` and `$n` (which I renamed to `$hi` and `$lo` for reasons that will soon become obvious):

```perl
my $hi = 0x00;
my $lo = 0x00;
while ( <$source_audio> ) {
    my $header = pack( 'C*',
       0x80, 0x78, $hi, $lo, 0x12, 0x34, 0x98, 0x76, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04 );
    
    ...

    if ( $lo == 0xFF ) {
        $lo = 0;
        ++$hi;
    } else {
        ++$lo;
    }
}
```

This could also be written as follows:

```perl
    $lo = ( $lo + 1 ) & 0xFF;
    ++$hi if !$lo;
```

But we're really just incrementing one number which is stored across two octets.

```perl
my $n = 0;
while ( <$source_audio> ) {
    my $hi = $n >> 8;
    my $lo = $n & 0xFF;
    my $header = pack( 'C*',
       0x80, 0x78, $hi, $lo, 0x12, 0x34, 0x98, 0x76, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04 );
    
    ...

    ++$n;
}
```

But let's leave the packing to `pack`! We're trying to store the value as a 16 bit unsigned int using big-endian byte order. Consulting [Formats for Packing and Unpacking Numbers](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=11111036) or the [documentation for `pack`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack) shows we can use `S>` or `n`.

```perl
my $n = 0;
while ( <$source_audio> ) {
   my $header = pack( 'C C n C*',
      0x80, 0x78, $n, 0x12, 0x34, 0x98, 0x76, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04 );
    
    ...

    ++$n;
}
```